# Exception handling in perl using Exception::Class

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am using [`Exception::Class`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exception%3a%3aClass) for handling exceptions

At the above link, in the Synopsis, it is shown that in order to check which exception has occurred, we need to compare the `$_->isa` to its value. So, if I have 4 exceptions of different types, then do I need to create a seperate base class for each of them and mention it as isa property. What if I dont mention the isa for exception class? How will I determine which exception it is? What is the best way to catch particular exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't, you just test for isa(your exception name).

You would only use isa if you want to group your exceptions into categories and be able to test for any of a category.  Just creating your 4 different types without isa properties, you will be able to test for them individually.

Comment: but the call : $_->isa(MyException) returns "" even when I catch MyException

Comment: Is "MyException" in quotes?

Comment: works for me: `use Try::Tiny; use Exception::Class "MyException"; try { MyException->throw("error"=>"errval") } catch { if ($_->isa("MyException")) { warn $_->error, "\n" } }`